# Remove UINavigationBar border

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

There is a thin gray border in the bottom of `UINavigatioBar`:
[image]

I can't remove it!

I've tried:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.borderColor =
 UIColor.orangeColor().CGColor
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.borderWidth = 0
```

With no chance.

Comment: @JackWu its in swift and other one in objective C

Comment: @JackWu I've tried that answer before asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

It should work

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Add this line for background color (Change rgb value of your choice)

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(rgba: "#000000")
```

Comment: Sorry, it was mistyping. `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.borderWidth = 0` does not work

Comment: @maysam set the background color

Comment: It does not work. Test it once yourself.